# video chat using pidgin?

Tags: pidgin

Hi i am very new to pidgin.Is it possible to do voice/video chat through talk using pidgin on windows??As in bolgs i found that its possible on linux but nor sure about windows.If its possible please tell me how is it possible.I already installed pidgin on windows but no option for voice/video chat is comming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sadly it is not.